# Closed form of harmonic sum with $\log(k)$ instead of $k$: $\sum _{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log (k)}$

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, harmonic-numbers

The harmonic number is well known to be defined as the finite sum of inverses of consecutive integers starting with 1:

$$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\tag{1}$$

Playing with other possibilities I wondered happens if we replace $k$ by $\log(k)$ (skipping over the term with $k=1$), i.e. what can be said about the sum

$$h_n = \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log(k)}\tag{2}$$

or, more generally,

$$h_{n}^{(p)} = \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log(k)^p}\tag{3}$$

Let us first find an integral representation.

Letting for $k\ge 2$

$$ \frac{1}{\log(k)} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t \log(k)} \,dt=\int_{0}^{\infty} k^{-t}\tag{4}$$

and doing the sum under the integral

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} k^{-t} = H_n^{(t)}-1\tag{5}$$

where $H_n^{(t)}$ is the generalized harmonic number of order $t$ defined by $(5)$,

we find the interesting expression

$$i_{n} =\int_{0}^{\infty}( H_n^{(t)}-1)\,dt\tag{6}$$

which contains an integral over the whole of the generalized harmonic number with respect to the second index.

**Question 1:** can you find a closed expression for this integral $(6)$ or the sum $(2)$ as a function of $n$?

**Question 2:** what is the asymptotic behaviour of $h_n$ or $i_n$ for $n\to \infty$?

Similarly with

$$\frac{1}{\log(k)^p} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)} \int_0^{\infty } t^{p-1} \exp (t (-\log (k))) \, dt\tag{7}$$

we have

$$h_{n}^{(p)} =\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{p-1}( H_n^{(t)}-1)\,dt\tag{8}$$

and the same questions as above for integer $p\ge 2$.

Comment: Presumably you meant $h_n$ where you wrote $i_n$ in $(6).$

Comment: While I doubt that's possible, we can easily show the sum is asymptotic to $\frac{n}{\log n}$.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews thank you for your remark. The use of different symbols is intended because the expresions mean the same but are not identical.

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_{k=\color{red}{2}}^{n} k^{-t} = H_n^{(t)}-1$ for $(5)$?

Comment: @VVejalla Yes, the sum must start at $k=2$. Typo corrected. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The sum is asymptotic to $\mathbb{li}(x)$ since $\int \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dx = \mathbb{li}(x)$, where $\mathbb{li}$ is the logarithmic integral.